# Проблема с русскими символами при установки пути к папкам пользователя

Tags: linux, debian, locale, kde

Помогите с проблемой.

```
OS: Debian 10 buster
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64
KDE 5.54.0 / Plasma 5.14.5
```

Параметры системы - Приложения - Пути к личным файлам. Например указываю путь к папке Изоражения (Русскими), сохраняю, все ок, но переход в другое меню и обратно -  вместо Папки изображения выдает такое:

```
/home/user/\xd0\x98\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f
```

Соответственно создается и папка с таким именем
Настройки locales переконфигурировал, не помогло
Вывод locale:

```
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru
LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_UA.UTF-8
```

Что это может быть?

Comment: Попробуй создать папку через mkdir Так же?

Comment: Также, без изменений

Comment: @I Zrchnsk Попробуйте в файл `env/setlocale.sh` добавить `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=ru:en`

Comment: У меня такого каталога нет, но принцип я понял. Это не помогает тоже

Comment: Изначально после установки системы - все работало. Потом просто при изменении одного пути к каталогу - все сбилось.

Comment: Неинтерпретированный UTF-8, вот что это у вас. А как вы добились такого?